# How to detect and write empty NFC tag?

Tags: android, nfc

I have to write an android app, which reads and writes NFC tags (only plain texts). If the TAG is writeable, and I touch it to my tablet, I can detect it, and I can write or read it. But, if I touch a new, empty tag, an other app
starts automatically. How can I prevent this, and write the empty tag?

Comment: What kind of tag are you using? Not all tags are supported for formatting in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write new, empty tags from within my apps. This requires to enable foreground dispatch of the NFC intents. See: [Using the Foreground Dispatch System](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch). There is also sample code available.